# What is key function pattern scope

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

My transformation is relatively big to post here, but I believe this is enough information to answer my question. Is the `match` pattern of the `key` function global for the document or it is relative to the context the function is called?

In other words, does the `key` function `match` pattern depend on the context the function is called from?

Comment: There is a `key` function which takes a key name, a key value and (in XSLT 2.0 and later) an optional node to define the subtree to search. And there is the `xsl:key` element which has a `match` attribute with a pattern. I don't know a `key` function taking a pattern. So are you asking about the `xsl:key` element? It is a top level element anyway, so I don't understand the question about scope or context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0, the `key()` function is limited to the current document.

In XSLT 2.0, the `key()` function has an optional third argument that allows you to specify the subtree on which it will operate.